# limits and continuity: irrational and rational piecewise function

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I have noticed similar topics, but people seem to solving them with sequences which I have not learned yet.

I need to prove that the function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x, & \text{ if $x$ is an irrational number }\\0 & \text{ if $x$ is a rational number }\end{cases}$$

is discontinuous at every irrational number using both the precise definition of a limit and the fact that every nonempty open interval of real numbers contains both irrational and rational numbers.

While I generally understand the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, I'm having trouble applying it to this question and finding the appropriate epsilon to use.

Comment: Think of it this way, no matter how close we get to any irrational number, x, there will always be a rational number, q, that is closer to x such that the distance between f(x) and f(q) ≥ x. We never reach our goal...

Comment: Hint. You can find a sequence of rational numbers that approaches $\sqrt{2}$. What is the limit if you apply $f$ to that sequence?

Comment: @user237393 I understand that there is an unlimited number of rational/irrational numbers in any interval, I am struggling with how to demonstrate that via the epsilon delta definition.

Comment: And @Ethan Bolker I cannot use sequences, because we have not covered them yet.

Comment: Perhaps you can turn what you _figure out_ using sequences into an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker That may be true for someone who knows what sequences are. But having not learned sequences yet,  and thus not knowing what they are or how to apply them, I can't really 'figure out' anything with them. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be irrational, so $f(a)=a\ne0$. Let $\epsilon=|a|$ and assume there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$. By the existence of rationals $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$ (for example $x=\frac1n\lfloor n a\rfloor$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n>\frac1\delta$) we arrive at a contradiction because for this $x$ we have $f(x)=0$ and hence $|f(x)-f(a)|\not<\epsilon$.

Comment: are the n's representing any real number? or..? I'm not familiar with what the fancy capitol N represents.

Comment: The fancy capital N is the standard symbol for the natural numbers (1, 2, 3, ...).

Comment: Can this be used to show that the function is continuous at zero?