# Limit of a piecewise function defined by x being rational or irrational

Tags: calculus, limits, irrational-numbers

If

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x² \quad \quad \text { if x is rational}
\newline 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text {if x is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$

prove that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0$

Comment: This post might help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271638/limits-and-continuity-irrational-and-rational-piecewise-function

Comment: @by24 thank you, but I wanted to prove it without the epsilon-delta approach. Can it be done?

Comment: Is it wrong to say that, no matter the direction we're approaching zero, we have infinitely many irrational and rational numbers, so either way the function always tends to zero?

Comment: No matter the direction we approach $5$ we have infinitely many irrational and rational numbers as well... but here $\lim\limits_{x\to 5}f(x)$ doesn't exist.  Your explanation is incomplete.  What is special about the function and zero specifically that has the function successfully have a limit there?

Comment: Thanks for noting! @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz replying you post-edit. I don't know if I understand what you're saying, the question is not asking to prove that the limit exists for any value that x approaches, only zero. Then, in that case, wouldn't it be enough to think like that? But you're right, if it was asking to prove that the limit exists for any value of a.

Comment: I am trying to point out that your logic that you had shared is flawed because the same logic would have otherwise worked if we had replaced zero with another number despite us knowing that it shouldn't have worked in that situation.

Comment: Ooooh now I get it! Yes, it would be incorrect to think like that if x wasn't approaching zero. I just noticed that, approaching zero, it doesn't matter if the number is rational or irrational (following the definition of the provided function), the function will always get closer to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the squeeze theorem and the fact that $-x^2 \le f(x) \le x^2$